# Create a KnowledgeGraphIndex object from Neo4j database

Tags: charts, neo4j, langchain, large-language-model, llama-index

I have an existing Neo4j database, and I would like to use LlamaIndex's `KnowledgeGraphIndex` to query this database via similarity search with an LLM. However, I saw on the documentation of LlamaIndex v0.10.15 that they only have examples of creating a `KnowledgeGraphIndex` object from text documents:

```
index = KnowledgeGraphIndex.from_documents(
    documents,
    storage_context=storage_context,
    max_triplets_per_chunk=2,
    include_embeddings=True,
)

query_engine = index.as_query_engine(
    include_text=True,
    response_mode="tree_summarize",
    embedding_mode="hybrid",
    similarity_top_k=5,
)
```

I am wondering if I can create `KnowledgeGraphIndex` objects from existing Neo4j databases instead of text chunks, such as a method that allows something like: `index = KnowledgeGraphIndex.from_graph_stores(neo4j_graph_store)`.

If this is not available, is there any other way to perform similarity search between a natural language question and a Neo4j graph database via LLM?